# File already exists exception file.copy

Tags: c#

I am trying to copy a driver file from my application folder to driver folder in windows 7. But as I run this program File already exists exception has been occurred if I check at driver folder manually the file does not exists at all.

```
Program.sDriverPath = Path.Combine(Program.sStartUpPath, @"windows7\amd64\MyDriver.sys");
string sPath = sDriverPath;
string sDestPath = Path.Combine(Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables(@"%windir%\system32"), @"drivers\MyDriver.sys");
MessageBox.Show("Source " + sDriverPath);
File.Copy(sDriverPath, sDestPath);
```

Comment: `File.Copy(sDriverPath, sDestPath, true);` add the third overload to specify that you want to overwrite the destination file.

Comment: CopyFile(sDriverPath, sDestPath, true); I did try But still not working

Comment: What SO are you using? 32 or 64 bits?

Comment: when you use the overload method and put true, what happens?

Comment: "Still not working" is not helpful. What happened? Did you receive an error?

Comment: When you copy that file manually, do you get a security warning (elevated permissions required)? That File.Copy will just abort then.

Comment: "File already exist exception" is not an exception that `File.Copy` throws at all. When the file already exists (and you are not overwriting), it throws `IOException`, that can also mean there's an I/O problem. What is the exact exception you are getting? Are you sure it's not `UnauthorizedAccessException`?

Comment: @jcl He's probably looking at the `Exception.Message` value, which will be something like `"The file '<name of file>' already exists."` if the file already exists.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to overwrite an existing file you need to use [the overload which has a boolean parameter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9706cfs5%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
public static void Copy(
string sourceFileName,
string destFileName,
bool overwrite)
```

and specify `true` for `overwrite`.

Now it is odd that you say the file doesn't exist in the destination at all - I think it must do, and you're not looking in the right place.

Try setting a breakpoint in your code immediately before you call `File.Copy()` and check the `sDestPath` parameter.

I suspect that what is happening is that the [`File System Redirector`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384187%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is silently redirecting your application to a different folder.

Try checking the folder `%windir%\SysWOW64` instead.

Finally, note that the process's user must be running as an administrator to write files into that location.

Comment: Is it in an overload, or is it just an argument with default value false?

Comment: @JohnDemetriou it is an overload

Comment: @Sakura yeah after review msdn docs I saw it :) but why though? wouldn't it make more sense if it was a default value?

Comment: @JohnDemetriou they have reason. If Microsoft don't do that, would you bother to visit MSDN?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Matthew Watson I found the solution. FSRedirector is redirecting system32 folder to SysWow64 folder.Go to syswow64 folder then go to drives folder you will find your file there.